# Delete curve points if they lie in a certain area

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have some number of curves.

[image]

I want the points starting from those in the 4th quadrant to be deleted (except for the points whose edge lies on the X axis). Like this:

[image]

I've tried this setup

[image]

and it gave unstable results.

[image]

I know why, but I don't understand how to fix it in a better way.

[image]

Comment: *"I want the points starting from those in the 4th quadrant to be deleted"* - I suspect there's an error here, how can a point "start" somewhere? Do you mean an edge? Also please mark the 4th quadrant or describe where it is (bottom-right?). *"(except for the points whose edge lies on the X axis). Like this:"* - but after deletion, there is no edge from 4th (bottom-right?) that would go through the x axis, so the exception seems unnecessary, or the example is poor or again the description is confusing. Please edit the question and clear the confusion.

Comment: Could please give more information about the curves. Which features do they have? For example: Can we expect all curves to touch all quadrants? Can we expect all curves to be arranged counter clockwise, so that the quadrants always are passed in the same sequence? Do all edges of all curves change their direction compared to their predecessor into the same direction (e.g. always to the left side, when moving counter-clockwise? May the 4th quadrant be passed multiple times by one curve - what should happen then? ...)

Answer (score 4):

I don’t know, if I interpreted your question right and if this answers it. So in either way it would be good, if you updated your question according to the comments from @MarkusvonBroady and me.

## The solution

Iterate over the points of every curve and for each curve delete all points after the first point in quadrant IV. This assumes, that the curves are oriented counterclockwise. You will find a detailed description of how the node setup works, below.

[image: 2D view of solution]

[image: node setup]

[image]

## How does it work

I will start with the iterating node: *Delete Geometry*. The nodes behind it are equal to your solution and only for visualizing.

[image: important nodes for the solution]

The *Delete Geometry* node iterates through all points of the mesh that is created by the *Curve to Mesh* node. It does this in the sequence of their IDs. Thus, it first iterates through all points of spline 1 from its first point to the last, then those of spline 2 and so on.

But how do we keep track of the fact, that we passed the first point in quadrant IV? That’s what the *Accumulate Field* node is for. It will be increased by the value of the *Switch* node for every point. And the *Switch* node is 1 in the case, that the current point is in quadrant IV (x > 0 and y < 0). In all other cases it is 0.

Leaving it like that, would delete all nodes of the second and third curve. We need a way to reset the *Accumulate Field* node for every curve. Here, the *Group ID* comes into play. We need a *Group ID* for every curve. Unfortunately, the spline IDs have been deleted by the *Curve to Mesh* node. By taking the *Capture Attribute* node, we write the spline ID to every point in the mesh, which is kept by the *Curve to Mesh* node. To use it, we simply need to connect the *Attribute* output of the *Capture Attribute* node to the *Group ID* input of the *Accumulate Field* node.

And as we want to delete starting at the node *after* the first node in quadrant for every curve, we use the *Trailing* output and not the *Leading* output of the *Accumulate Field* node.

## Another solution

Another possibility would be to select the points in the fourth quadrant using vector mathematics.

To do this, normalize the position vector of the points and form the dot product with the vector pointing in the direction of the fourth quadrant. In this case, that is $(1,-1,0)$. If the dot product is greater than or equal to $1$, the points are in the desired area and can be removed. Since the points of your curves are all oriented the same way (counterclockwise), the *Accumulate Fields* node helps here as well to be able to select and delete all points with a higher index according to the selection made before.

This could look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Good to have you back, André :)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, thanks for the welcome.

Comment: @quellenform, thanks for the vector-based supplement.